# How to a vertical master detail query?

Tags: mysql

I want product name to display blank field if same product came before .

```
product_name    | colors_available | items_left
JUMPAN TSHIRT   | red              | 3
                | blue             | 2
                | black            | 9
B.BALL CUP      | red              | 10
```

can i get this ouput using mysql query?

Comment: In my sample output. I have a product name jumpman which have 3 colors and bball cup with 1 color. can i use left join have an ouput like this? where the product name becomes blank if the product id before it is the same

Answer (score 2):

**You probably want to do this on the client side / in your application, not on the database server.** This would give your application all information to still reference each row for further action. The unique identifier in your example would be the combination `(product_name, colors_available)` - this information is lost, when you change your output on the server side.

---

If you still want to do it in mysql...

Let's assume `your_query` returns data like this right now:

```
+---------------+------------------+------------+
| product_name  | colors_available | items_left |
+---------------+------------------+------------+
| JUMPAN TSHIRT | red              |          3 |
| JUMPAN TSHIRT | blue             |          2 |
| JUMPAN TSHIRT | black            |          9 |
| B.BALL CUP    | red              |         10 |
+---------------+------------------+------------+
```

The following query will suppress output of `product_name` whenever the current `product_name` doesn't change to the row before:

```
SELECT
        -- compare current row's product_name to local variable
    IF( yq.product_name = @last_product_name,
        -- if they match return NULL
        NULL,
        -- if they don't match update local variable to current product_name
        @last_product_name := yq.product_name
      ) AS product_name,
    yq.colors_available,
    yq.items_left
FROM (your_query) AS yq
```

This will result in the following output:

```
+---------------+------------------+------------+
| product_name  | colors_available | items_left |
+---------------+------------------+------------+
| JUMPAN TSHIRT | red              |          3 |
| NULL          | blue             |          2 |
| NULL          | black            |          9 |
| B.BALL CUP    | red              |         10 |
+---------------+------------------+------------+
```

You can change `NULL` to `''` to return an empty string, of course.